# Latex Plugin with CK Editor to create mathematical formulas

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, latex, mathjax

I am using the [Latex Plugin for CkEditor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/about.php). This plugin returns the Math Equation in Image form.

I am looking to get hold of Latex text instead of image. How do I achieve it? Is there a configuration to enable it? Example would be great.

Please refer following code.

```
CKEDITOR.extraPlugins = 'mathjax,eqneditor';

CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('eqneditor', '../../vendors/ckeditor-ext-plugins/eqneditor/plugin.js');

CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
        {name:'document',items:[ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'EqnEditor'],
        }
    ];
```

**Edited**

P.S. : I need a Panel to edit a math equation, something like this http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Answer (score 0):

You are now using a third-party plugin, nothing wrong with that of course, however, you would need to ask its authors for support as the core CKEditor team is unable to support external addons.

There is, however, also the [official CKEditor Mathematical Formulas](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax) plugin available - you are referencing it in your code (CKEDITOR.extraPlugins = 'mathjax';) but it seems you are not using it.

See the sample here: http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/mathjax.html

With this plugin you can write equations in TeX. I am not sure what you mean by "getting hold of Latex text", but for this plugin the equations will be output in plain TeX format with MathJax delimiters, `\(` and `\)`, so the source HTML will look like this:

```
<p><span class="math-tex">\(P(E) = {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{ n-k} \)</span></p>
```

Refer to the documentation for more information about this plugin and its configuration: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_mathjax

Comment: The real problem is, If I used just MathJax, then User may not able to formulate the equation. I need something which is Graphical and easy to use to formulate the answer. http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php Is URL has panel to edit the Math Question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a plugin that allows to construct math equations visually instead of the user typing latex you can try the WIRIS plugin in your CKEditor. It referenced [here on CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/addon/ckeditorwiris) and [here on Wiris](http://www.wiris.com/solutions/ckeditor)

Answer (score 0):

[image]Here is one of the mathjax plugin,
few button miss this repo. https://github.com/bagana89/CKeditorMathJaxPlugin

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, tailor your answers to the question. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/311792